# Custom Markers for Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, markers

I have searched google and everyone says its not supported. I was wondering if there are any open community matlab functions which would be able to plot a user defined png as a marker. The closest I found was 
http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39487-custom-marker-plot/content/plotCustMark/plotCustMark.m . But it doesn't serve the intended purpose . 
Let me know if its even possible for me to write something up for this ! Thanks.

**Additional Problem** : Okay I have this weird problem now . my png has a black background !! I dont understand why. I tried to lower the alpha value still doesn't work.

**Solution** : The problems I mentioned in the comments to @brainkz can be solved by

http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/144411-displaying-image-over-background-making-top-image-background-color-transparent

**Method** : Import the transparency settings of your image through

```
[marker,map,transperancy ] = imread('car.png');
```

and later set

```
handleIm = imagesc([x_low x_high], [y_low y_high], marker)
set(handleIm ,'AlphaData',transperancy);
```

**Clarification** : The images were all transperant but since I was overlaying it over another image it turned the current images background to default black. I posted a solution to this problem which I guess would be really useful to a lot of people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`imagesc` can put the png on you plot. We can avail ourselves of this in the following way:

Define user data:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 5*rand(size(x)) + 2.5;
```

Load the marker image:

```
marker = imread('icon.png');
```

Define marker size and adjust the `x` and `y` data:

```
markersize = [1,1]; %//The size of marker is expressed in axis units, NOT in pixels
x_low = x - markersize(1)/2; %//Left edge of marker
x_high = x + markersize(1)/2;%//Right edge of marker
y_low = y - markersize(2)/2; %//Bottom edge of marker
y_high = y + markersize(2)/2;%//Top edge of marker
```

Then, we put our loaded image on the plot at the specified points

```
for k = 1:length(x)
    imagesc([x_low(k) x_high(k)], [y_low(k) y_high(k)], marker)
    hold on
end
axis equal
hold off
```

At the end, you are likely to get the following:

[image]

To achieve the desired appearance, you would need to play with the parameters for a while.

Hope that helps

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `axis equal` outside the loop?

Comment: Good suggestion @Sardar_Usama

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this would need a bit tinkering speacially with different layers in my plot. But as of now it does something i intended it to do . Cheers !

Comment: I wonder are there any ways to hide the marker ? every loops I want a new marker but hide the previous one @brainkz

Comment: Okay I have this weird problem now . my png has a black background !! I dont understand why. I tried to lower the alpha value still doesnt work

Comment: Inside the loop you need to use `h(k) = plot(...)` to get the handle to the element plotted and `delete(h(k-1))` to delete the previous marker.

Comment: Well, I can't think of anything but changing the image @Sayantan_Roy

Comment: You should use .png images with transparent background! I think this will definitely solve the problem!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama   The images were all transperant but since I was overlaying it over another image it turned the current images background to default black. I posted a solution to this problem which I guess would be really useful to a lot of people.

Comment: @brainkz consider adding the solution, he proposed, to your answer! It is highly possible that someone will flag that because questions are not a place to answer a problem!