# Is it possible to change markers in Matlab plot function?

Tags: matlab, plot, markers

I am trying to use matlab plot function to create a plot. However, the markers available are limited. For example:

```
plot(x,y,'-o')
```

will plot with circle markers.

However, if I want a marker with the arrow symbol or a letter, this is not possible. Does anyone know of any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer : If you want custom markers, its convenient to make the plot in some other plotting software, like [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/).

Long answer :

1. If you want a simple text marker, e.g. the letter 'A', then its possible as follows ([source](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93787-how-do-i-use-custom-markers-for-a-line-object-in-a-matlab-plot#answer_103138))

   ```matlab
   font = 'Lucida Sans Typewriter';  % choose a font

   m = 'A';  % choose desired character

   x = 0:.5:2*pi;    

   y = sin(x);    

   % Use TEXT to plot the character along the data    

   text(x,y,m,'fontname',font,'color','red')    

   % Manually set axis limits, since TEXT does not do this for you    

   xlim([min(x) max(x)])    

   ylim([min(y) max(y)])
   ```
2. If you want a more complicated marker, then I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38762194/842808) on stackoverflow.

Comment: For 1st point, it's possible to create plot by looping through the data using `text`.
For 2nd point there is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38762194/3406719) where I tried using images as markers

Comment: I have tried using text() before. But it plots the letter to the right of the specified xy coordinates. So it does not plot at the point itself.

I guess I will have to use it for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Tyler Yes I noticed that. Matlab places the letter such that if (x,y) is the speified coordinate for the text, x corresponds to the leftmost pixel of the glyph and y corresponds to the vertical center of the glyph. If for a glyph the width and height can be obtained, then one can place the glyph such that (x,y) lies exactly at the centroid of the glyph.

Comment: Since this was marked as answer in another (duplicate) question, let me just add one thing: The alignment problem can be solved using the additional parameters `'HorizontalAlignment','Center','VerticalAlignment','middle'` to `text`.