# Scatter Plot with 9 different colors and symbol

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix thats last column is the datas label. I have created a scatter plot to plot the points. What I want is plot each of the class labels in different colors. The class labels are the numbers 1 through 9. So instead of the circles, or the mrks in the matlab scatter function, I would like the actually number.

I have this right now:

```
scatter(score_r(:,1), score_r(:,2), 30, categorical(label), 'filled');
```

And tried this but did not work:

```
gscatter(score_r(:,1), score_r(:,2), categorical(label), '1', '2',  '3',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '7',  '8',  '9');
```

How can I do this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Markers for Matlab plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761718/custom-markers-for-matlab-plot)

Comment: while the answer mentioned in the duplicate link can be used, it is in my view not satisfactory, as a simpler text base solution should be also possible

Comment: what you ask  is not clear can you give an image what what you expect to get?

Comment: Sounds like you should make the markers filled white circles (assuming the background is also white), and add `text` at the position of every marker.