# How to plot two 2D histograms on the same 2D image?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I wonder if anyone can help me to plot two 2D histograms on the same plot.
I do some lifetime imaging and I want to reproduce my result as histograms (phasor plot method). I know how to plot a single 2D histogram, but not more, without removing the preceding one.

I am currently using the DIPimage toolbox, but I have seen that for plotting 2D histograms you can use as well the function 'ndhist'.

[image]

Please, find attached the picture. This is not obviously what I am after, as the background should be all blue and I would like to plot more 'clouds' over the universal circle.

Comment: What langage are you using? Is it Matlab/Octave? If so please add the proper tags. Also, please share your efforts. I think you might benefit from taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Markers for Matlab plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761718/custom-markers-for-matlab-plot)