# Add image in Octave plot instead of color

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot, octave, gnu

I want to create an animation of hydrogen atom with one proton at centre and one electron revolving around. But instead of adding colour to it, I want to add image
i.e.

```
plot3(x,y,z,'.','markersize',10,'r')
```

Above code will give me a point at location `(x,y,z)` of color red. But instead of red color, I want an image in it uploaded below.

[image]

Is it possible with Octave?

Comment: JFI: For 2D plots, it has been answered before: [Custom Markers for Matlab plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38761718/5698672)

Comment: In MATLAB, to obtain a marker like above, you may do: `x=linspace(0,1,10);` `y=sin(2*pi*x);`  `z=cos(2*pi*x);` `scatter3(x,y,z,'ro','filled','SizeData',100);`
`hold on;`
`h=plot3(x, y,z,'wo','markersize',5);`
`pause(0.01);`
`h.MarkerHandle.Style = 'hbar';`

Note that hbar is an undocumented property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged this question `gnuplot` I will give an answer in the form of a gnuplot command.  I leave it to someone else to show how to pass this command through to gnuplot from inside octave. This syntax assumes the current version of gnuplot (5.4)

```
set pixmap 1 "TaGR5m.jpg" at x,y,z center
```

This will use the native size of the image.  If you need to rescale it, add the additional qualifiers `width <dx>`, `height <dy>`, or `size <dx>,<dy>`.